# Correcting Specific Values in SSIS Package.

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am building a report for one of our departments that counts  software licenses by cost center. The problem I have is we have our upper level management that is in a specific cost center for organizational purposes (which the license system grabs) but the department requesting the report needs to have the cost center that the managers expense everything to instead.

- this effects about 15 entries but the report pulls over 300, so I only need to correct the 15 without impacting the rest.

I have created a table labeled [dbo].[CostCenter_corrections] with two columns in it [UserID] (nvarchar, this is the user name not an employee ID) and [CostCenter_Correction] (int, this is their expense cost center).

What I want to do is either set up a method at the end of the Staging Load that will correct these numbers by the UserID, like an executeSQL Task, or build another SSIS package that will process the Staging Data and reload it into the same staging table (not sure if that is possible or even something that should be done).

If you can think of any other way I'm open to ideas.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you running into a problem using an `Execute Tsql Task` to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not leave the SSIS stuff alone and use that table of "other cost centres" for this report only?

Comment: Why not apply the corrections while doing the Staging load itself? Use a lookup task or the likes to look up the correction and If it exists then use the corrected value else the use the value in the table. Avoids unnecessary housekeeping after the actual load process.

Comment: @DanielE. Yes, I have tried to build a script using a previous project as the template. However, I can not get it to work. Either the parameters are too different or I'm not setting it up correctly. Im not familiar enough with TSQL to determine that.

Comment: @DanBracuk, I need all of the cost centers in the report. But i need to replace the 15 cost centers in the main (or staging table) with the ones from the "Other Cost Centers".

Comment: @TMNT2014, That's what I want to do but when I tried that it didn't provide all of the cost centers, just the ones that it found in the look up.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to set the lookup to "Redirect rows to no match output" (you can do this from the genaral tab) and then you will have two outputs from the lookup, one for matched rows and one for not matched. Then you can do the work you need and union the two pipelines back. Your DF will look like this:

[image]